# Function for this series of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I have $f(n)$:

- $f\left(1\right)=1$
- $f\left(2\right)=2$
- $f\left(3\right)=3$
- $f\left(4\right)=3$

How can I solve the next $f(n)$?

I came to this problem while been working on my algorithm.

Here is an example to how $f(n)$ might looks like

$1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,\dots$

Comment: If $f(i+2)=3$, then for all $n\ge 3$ we have $f(n)=3$. I think there is some error.

Comment: Yes there was error in question, I edited it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a function which gives that pattern, try $$f(n)=\lfloor\sqrt{4n-3}\rfloor=\lceil\sqrt{2n}\rceil+1$$ slightly adapted from [OEIS A000267](https://oeis.org/A000267)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the website.